# Execute sql command which return a declared sql table using EF

Tags: sql, entity-framework, datareader, strongly-typed-dataset

I have following SQL Query which I want to run using EF :

```
DECLARE @Users TABLE(Id INT, Name NVARCHAR(1000),Family NVARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @Users 
SELECT dbo.AspNetUsers.Id,dbo.AspNetUsers.FirstName,dbo.AspNetUsers.LASTNAME,
 FROM dbo.AspNetUsers 
Where dbo.AspNetUsers.ID IN 
( SELECT users.ID FROM res.UserTag JOIN dbo.AspNetUsers users ON users.ID = UserTag.UserID WHERE TagID IN (8))
select * from @Users result
```

When I run it through this method :

```
dbcontext.DbSet().SqlQuery(query, "")
```

But it throws an error as below :

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Data.Models.AspNetUser'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Actually, I want to cast the result to a another type (not defined in EF models), and I don`t want to use ASPNETUSER model, so I tried this:

```
if (_unitOfWork.Context().Database.Connection.State!=ConnectionState.Open)
                _unitOfWork.Context().Database.Connection.Open();

            DbCommand cmd = _unitOfWork.Context().Database.Connection.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = procedureName;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                return dr;
            }
```

But the datareadr (dr) has no records in this case.

**Updated**:

I found the solution. First of all, I have to put "Select ... " statement in the end of the query, also I can use custom type when calling db.Database.SqlQuery.

Comment: You can answer your own question. Do not edit the answer into the question but put it in the answer box provided please.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. First of all, I have to put "Select ... " statement in the end of the query, also I can use custom type when calling db.Database.SqlQuery.